# Redirecting WCF service URL to a different web page

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service that is accessed via clients with a .svc extension at a url, e.g. http://MyHost/MyService.svc

When that address is put in to a web browser, I get the "You have created a service" page. What I'd like to do is have this page be a different HTML page. A static page is fine.

I have read [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5778651a-b212-438a-b3e8-f7029775d52a/custom-html-help-page-for-httpget-for-an-iis6-hosted-wcf-service?forum=wcf), but from what I can tell, it includes a way to redirect the base URL address to anoth

Comment: I'm clear about what you mean, have you tried the solution in the article you posted?  If so, is there specific behavior that it causes that you do not expect?

Comment: At the end of the article, it states: "Run it, and then hit the base address in a browser". It seems to be a method to redirect the base address, and not the full address with the .svc extension.